# How do I decode this text?

Tags: ascii, escaping, decode

I have a friend who has code like this in his wordpress files:

> Blockquote
>   \x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69
>   Blockquote

And so on...

How do I decode this?  Is there an online tool to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode it online using the 'Hex to ASCII' tool at: 
http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/index.php

You don't paste in the 'Blockquote', but everything in between the blockquote tags.

Comment: It works with the mode "Hex to ASCII" and all "\x" removed.
The function return the string value "functi", as Blah said.

Comment: It even works with the \x markers left intact, so there's no need to manipulate the string.

Answer (score 2):

The text is an ASCII representation of some hexidecimal characters, how you would decode it would depend very much on the programming language you were using.  [Here is a sample of a recent hex to ASCII post that may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412954/converting-binary-data-to-printable-hex#412975).

Answer (score 0):

It's just hex...  It converts to: "functi"